# How to deal with inconsistent dates in Django?

Tags: django, date, datetime, django-models

I am trying to show the birth and death dates for artists. Some artists have incomplete dates. For example: Johannes Vermeer is "Delft, October, 1632 - Delft, 15 December, 1675".

How can one deal with this in Django model.Datefield()? Should I save the year, month and day separately?

Comment: Check this out: https://pypi.org/project/django-partial-date/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not save the year, month and day seperately, since that would be a headache to filter, order, validate etc. (What if the user enters 31 may? What about leap years etc.?)

You could use django-partial-date, but the implementation itself is fairly straightforward.

If you don't like to add dependencies, I would just go with one DateField, and a CharField that has three choices:year, year and month, and full_date. The CharFields could then contain a DateFormat of the different types of partial dates.
Something like this:

```
DATE_TYPES = [
    ('%Y', 'Year only'),
    ('%m %Y', 'Year and month'),
    ('%d %m %Y', 'Full year'),
]

class Artist(models.Model):
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    birth_date_type = models.CharField(choices = DATE_TYPES)
```

This way, you can easily filter and format all sorts of dates just by using

```
artist.birth_date.format(artist.birth_date_type)
```

Comment: Sorry, they're supposed to be tuples, so written like this: ('%Y', 'Year only'). I have edited my answer accordingly